# Macro for Automating Truth Tables

Tags: tables, macros, programming, logic

I used this truth table when writing a proof.[image]
Unfortunately I made a tiny typo; The first time around, I misplaced an additional `ʹ` symbol, which just happened to make the output exactly wrong. It ended up taking me forever to understand why nothing after that seemed to add up the way I knew it should.

It led me to wonder. Is it possible to build some kind of macro that will allow me to generate accurate truth tables according to a given input? In other words: I'd like it to work something like:

`\truthtable{A, B, ( A \oplus B )', (A) \oplus (B')}`

As opposed to having to draw the entire thing manually, potentially making errors. How would you even begin to program something like this in LaTeX?

Here's the full manual MWE for the table pictured above:

---

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%hdashline
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%        
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\toprule%%–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
$A$ & $B$ & $(A \oplus B)'$ & $(A) \oplus (B')$ \\
\midrule%%–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hdashline%%··········································
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hdashline%%··········································
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hdashline%%··········································
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \bottomrule%––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Do you want the `0` and `1` to fill in somehow automatically based on the column headers or yould you be satisfied with manually entering thouse entries?

Comment: Well, I already have manually entered those values. But yes, the idea is to give it the column headers, and have it calculate the output accordingly, to preclude any inaccuracies. Plus it would just be super quick and convenient. Eventually I would like to make a whole collection of similar tools to help make latex a breeze

Comment: This looks like something that would be fairly easy to do with LuaTeX. There are some python truth table calculators on github that would be easy to adapt to Lua I should think. e.g. https://gist.github.com/a-andreyev/8b72ed4f7913da7b35313044185f6e11

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible with pure TeX/LaTeX too though?

Comment: One way to do this would be to use the `collcell` package and define a column type that compute the given function. The you would leave the output cells empty and the value would be computed based on the input values.  This would require that you define macros that compute the output values based on the input columns (which may be more work than manually verifying a table).  But, if you need many of the types of tables often then it may be worthwhile.

Comment: Yes, you can also program a Mars rover in TeX (among other things) [What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/104248) but just because you can, doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn But this is not at all bizarre IMHO. If there is a clear prescription, then TeX can do the nasty things for you, After all, you also do not use `lualatex` to draw trees, do you? What is lacking here is a clear prescription what the input is, and what should be done with it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm not saying it's bizarre, or undoable of course, just easier to do with a programming language rather than TeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK, if you are not saying it is bizarre, then I do not necessarily disagree with the comment. I do not know what `(A\oplus B)'` and so on mean, but from what I think they may mean the table can easily done with `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat A⨁B should mean exclusive or. I assume the ′ is being used as complement otherwise the truth table makes no sense.

Comment: @AlanMunn So `\oplus` -> `\lor` and `'` -> `\lnot`? Maybe. Should be clarified by the OP IMHO. `pgf` math understands `and`, `or` and `not`, so it can be done with `pgfplotstable` if that's the interpretation.

Comment: @Schrödinger Yes, the ⨁ symbol is the bitwise XOR (actually addition mod2) operator, similar to **⊻**. The prime/apostrophe-looking thing is a suffix denoting the bitwise complement of the preceding value. Such that A=1 ⟺ A'=0. So A' is similar to ¬A or Ᾱ. It's arguably the standard notation used in computer science, cryptography, etc. It's become second nature to me; I sometimes forget not everybody is familiar with it. Although it's more of a suggestion than anything. If you have an idea for a solution, I imagine it would be fairly trivial to substitute symbols, or make minor adjustments.

Comment: @AlanMunn Regarding _"Yes, you can also program a Mars rover in TeX"_, and _"..just because you can, doesn't mean you should"_ –– You're right, it doesn't mean I should.. but does it mean I shouldn't? Because I want to. I kind of want to learn how to program a Mars rover with TeX now too. Not because it's practical though, just cos it sounded cool when you said it..

Comment: I used a python script to generate the TeX code, which worked well and was out-of-the-box. But, obviously, if you are wanting a challenge, that's not an advantage ;).

Answer (score 10):

This is something quickly written. Does not steer the Mars rover, in fact it is just a one-liner. If you make your code copyable I will add all the table options, if needed. (In fact, I made zero efforts to make the output "pretty", nor to suppress spaces or empty lines.) Also one can use a loop to create all the rows. I added explanations to the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\myrow}[2]{ #1 & #2 & 
 \pgfmathparse{not(int(mod(#1+#2,2)))}\pgfmathresult & 
 \pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1+not(#2),2))}\pgfmathresult\\
 }
\setcounter{step}{0}
\def\tabcontent{\stepcounter{step}\ifnum\value{step}<5
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myA}{(\value{step}-1)/2}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myB}{mod(\value{step}-1,2)}%
\edef\temp{\noexpand\myrow{\myA}{\myB}}\temp%
\tabcontent\fi}
\begin{document}
In the first example (Table~\ref{tab:First}), explicit macros
\verb|\myrow{A}{B}| are used for each row. The \verb|\myrow| macro takes two
arguments, which are $A$ and $B$ in your application. 

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{}cccc@{}}
 ~$A$~ & ~$B$~ & $(A \oplus B)'$ & $(A) \oplus (B')$ \\
 \hline
 \myrow{0}{0}
 \myrow{0}{1}
 \myrow{1}{0}
 \myrow{1}{1}
\end{tabular} 
\caption{First example.}
\label{tab:First}
\end{table}

The important point is that the other entries of the remaining columns can be
computed with \texttt{pgf} via \verb|\pgfmathparse{not(int(mod(#1+#2,2)))}| and
\verb|\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1+not(#2),2))}|, respectively. I strongly suspect
that other packages like \texttt{xint} allow you to do similar things. However,
I am most familiar with \texttt{pgf}.

In the second example (Table~\ref{tab:Second}), a loop produces the content
of the table. Since the \& character is notoriously nasty, this loop is realized
as a recursive macro. Alternatives to this recursion include the \verb|\gappto|
macro that comes with the \texttt{etoolbox} package.
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{}cccc@{}}
 ~$A$~ & ~$B$~ & $(A \oplus B)'$ & $(A) \oplus (B')$ \\
 \hline
 \tabcontent
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Second example.}
\label{tab:Second}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _"This is something ultra quickly written."_ No worries, I appreciate your input. _"..in fact it is just a one-liner."_ That might actually be my favourite kind. _"If you make your code copyable.."_ Can you not copy it? What do you need me to do?

Comment: So, in the meantime, what have you done here exactly? Can we walk through it a little? I guess you imported a library (`\usepackage{pgf}`) to access the `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathresult` commands which seem to calculate and print the correct values based on their input. Then you declare it as a function by wrapping it between `\newcommand{\myrow}[2]{ #1 & #2 &` and `}`; `{\myrow}` gives it a name, `[2]` declares the input/argument count where `#1` and `#2` correspond with the argument values and `&` is the alignment operator. Am I close?

Comment: @tjt263 That’s basically correct. I am traveling right now, so I won’t dare to edit the answer on my cell phone. \myrow creates a row of the table, and, as you say, it takes two arguments, the values of A and B which it Prints and uses for the entries of the other two columns. The main point, though, is that pgf has the functions you need built in, as this illustrates. (There are other packages that do that, too.)

Comment: @tjt263 Copyable means that there should not be any nonstandard characters in, as there are e.g. after \toprule in the comments. Also make sure the code can be compiled.

Comment: very helpful answer!

Answer (score 6):

The not so short answer, where the code turned out to be longer than in my head. The code may look a bit cumbersome, but I did not optimise it in any way. I just wanted to show a solution where the input is interpreted and a truthtable is generated e.g. `(A\oplus B)'` as A XOR B and the result is negated. The code does not accept every possible inputs. For example, there must only be one logical operator: `\land`, `\lor` and `\oplus`. So `(A\land B) \land \neg (A\land B)` is not a valid input. There can be multiple operators like `\neg` and `'`.

It should be possible to extend the code to overcome this limitation.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_op_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_seq

\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_right_tl
\tl_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_out_tl

\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_op_seq

\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_vara_logical_seq
\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_varb_logical_seq
\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_op_logical_seq

\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_seq
\seq_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_split_seq

\int_new:N \l__truthtable_expression_int
\int_new:N \g__truthtable_tmp_int

\bool_new:N \l__truthtable_vara_bool
\bool_new:N \l__truthtable_varb_bool
\bool_new:N \l__truthtable_result_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\truthtable}{ m m m }
{
    \group_begin:
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__truthtable_expression_seq {#3}
    \int_set:Nn \l__truthtable_expression_int { \seq_count:N \l__truthtable_expression_seq }
    
    \seq_map_function:NN  \l__truthtable_expression_seq \truthtable_parse:n
    \truthtable_truthtable:NNnn \l__truthtable_expression_seq \l__truthtable_expression_int {#1} {#2}
    \group_end:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_truthtable_begin:N #1
{
    \tabular{ *{ \int_eval:n { #1 + 2 } }{ >{$}c<{$} } }
    \toprule
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_truthtable_end:
{
    \\ \bottomrule
    \endtabular
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_truthtable:NNnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
    \truthtable_truthtable_begin:N #2
    \truthtable_truthtable_header:NNnn #1 #2 {#3} {#4}
    \truthtable_truthtable_content:N   #2
    \truthtable_truthtable_end:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_truthtable_header:NNnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
    #3 & #4
    \int_compare:nNnF {#2} = { 0 }
    {  & \seq_use:Nn #1 { & }  }
    \\ \midrule
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_truthtable_content:N #1
{
    \int_gzero:N \g__truthtable_tmp_int
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 1 }
    {
        \int_step_inline:nnn { 0 } { 1 }
        {
            ##1 & ####1
            
            \truthtable_evaluate:Nnn #1 {##1} {####1}
            
            \__truthtable_newline:N \g__truthtable_tmp_int
        }   
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__truthtable_newline:N #1
{
    \int_gincr:N #1
    \int_compare:nNnF {#1} = { 4 }
    { \\ }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_parse:n #1
{
    \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \__truthtable_get_operator:n
    
    \__truthtable_split_at_operator:n {#1}
    
    \truthtable_if_odd:VTF \l__truthtable_expression_left_tl
    {  \truthtable_odd:NN  \l__truthtable_expression_left_tl \l__truthtable_expression_right_tl  }
    {  \truthtable_even:NN \l__truthtable_expression_left_tl \l__truthtable_expression_right_tl  }
    
    
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__truthtable_get_operator:n #1
{
    \str_case:nnT {#1}
    {
        { \oplus } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__truthtable_op_seq { xor } }
        { \lor   } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__truthtable_op_seq { or  } }
        { \land  } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__truthtable_op_seq { and } }
    }
    {  \tl_map_break:n { \tl_set:Nn \l__truthtable_op_tmp_tl {#1} }  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__truthtable_split_at_operator:n #1
{
    \exp_args:NNV
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__truthtable_expression_split_seq \l__truthtable_op_tmp_tl {#1}
    
    \tl_set:Nx \l__truthtable_expression_left_tl  { \seq_item:Nn \l__truthtable_expression_split_seq { 1 } }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__truthtable_expression_right_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__truthtable_expression_split_seq { 2 } }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_odd:NN #1 #2
{
    \tl_clear:N \l__truthtable_expression_out_tl
    \tl_reverse:N #2
    \truthtable_odd_aux:NNn #1 \l__truthtable_expression_tmp_tl { ( }
    \truthtable_odd_aux:NNn #2 \l__truthtable_expression_tmp_tl { ) }
    \tl_reverse:N #2
    
    \truthtable_get_logicals:NN \l__truthtable_expression_out_tl \l__truthtable_op_logical_seq
    \truthtable_get_logicals:NN #1 \l__truthtable_vara_logical_seq
    \truthtable_get_logicals:NN #2 \l__truthtable_varb_logical_seq
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_odd_aux:NNn #1 #2 #3
{
    \tl_set_eq:NN #2 #1
    
    \tl_map_inline:Nn #1
    {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {##1} {#3}
        {
            \tl_set:Nx #2 { \tl_tail:N #2 }
            \tl_map_break:
        }
        {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l__truthtable_expression_out_tl { \tl_head:N #2 }
            \tl_set:Nx #2 { \tl_tail:N #2 }
        }
    }
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 #2
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_even:NN #1 #2
{
    \truthtable_get_logicals:NN #1 \l__truthtable_vara_logical_seq
    \truthtable_get_logicals:NN #2 \l__truthtable_varb_logical_seq
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__truthtable_op_logical_seq { }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_get_logicals:NN #1 #2
{
    \tl_clear:N \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_tl
    \tl_map_inline:Nn #1
    {
        \str_case:nn {##1}
        {
            { '    } { \truthtable_add_to_tl:Nnn \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_tl { not } { , } }
            { \neg } { \truthtable_add_to_tl:Nnn \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_tl { not } { , } }
        }
    }
    \seq_put_right:NV #2 \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_tl
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_add_to_tl:Nnn #1 #2 #3
{
    \tl_if_empty:NTF #1
    {  \tl_set:Nn       #1 {  #2}  }
    {  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 {#3#2}  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_evaluate:Nnn #1 #2 #3
{
    \int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } {#1}
    {
        &
        \truthtable_set_bool:Nn \l__truthtable_vara_bool {#2}
        \truthtable_set_bool:Nn \l__truthtable_varb_bool {#3}
        \truthtable_eval_logical:NNn \l__truthtable_vara_logical_seq \l__truthtable_vara_bool {##1}
        \truthtable_eval_logical:NNn \l__truthtable_varb_logical_seq \l__truthtable_varb_bool {##1}
        
        \truthtable_eval_operator:NNn \l__truthtable_vara_bool \l__truthtable_varb_bool {##1}
        \truthtable_print_result:NNn \l__truthtable_op_logical_seq \l__truthtable_result_bool {##1}
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_eval_operator:NNn #1 #2 #3
{
    \str_case_e:nn { \seq_item:Nn \l__truthtable_op_seq {#3} }
    {
        { xor } { \truthtable_xor:NN #1 #2 }
        { or  } { \truthtable_or:NN  #1 #2 }
        { and } { \truthtable_and:NN #1 #2 }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_eval_logical:NNn #1 #2 #3
{
    \exp_args:NNx
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_seq { \seq_item:Nn #1 {#3} }
    
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__truthtable_logical_tmp_seq
    {
        \str_case:nn {##1}
        {
            { not } { \truthtable_not:N #2 }
        }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_print_result:NNn #1 #2 #3
{
    \truthtable_eval_logical:NNn #1 #2 {#3}
    
    \bool_if:NTF #2
    { 1 }
    { 0 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_set_bool:Nn #1 #2
{
    \int_case:nn {#2}
    {
        { 0 } { \bool_gset_false:N #1 }
        { 1 } { \bool_gset_true:N  #1 }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_xor:NN #1 #2
{
    \bool_xor:nnTF {#1} {#2}
    { \bool_set_true:N  \l__truthtable_result_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__truthtable_result_bool }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_not:N #1
{
    \bool_set_inverse:N #1
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_or:NN #1 #2
{
    \bool_lazy_or:nnTF {#1} {#2}
    { \bool_set_true:N  \l__truthtable_result_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__truthtable_result_bool }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \truthtable_and:NN #1 #2
{
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF {#1} {#2}
    { \bool_set_true:N  \l__truthtable_result_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__truthtable_result_bool }
}

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \truthtable_if_odd:n #1 { T, F, TF }
{
    \regex_count:nnN { \( } {#1} \l_tmpa_int
    \regex_count:nnN { \) } {#1} \l_tmpb_int
    
    \int_if_odd:nTF { \l_tmpa_int + \l_tmpb_int }
    {  \prg_return_true:   }
    {  \prg_return_false:  }
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \truthtable_if_odd:n { V } { TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \truthtable{A}{B}
    {
        (A\oplus B)',
        (A)\oplus(B'),
        A\oplus B,
        A\oplus B',
        \neg((A)\oplus (B)'),
        A\lor B,
        A\lor B',
        A\land B
    }
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]